# Take N elements of a window in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

Say I have this:

```
df = (polars
  .DataFrame(dict(
    j=numpy.random.randint(10, 99, 20),
    ))
  .with_row_count()
  .select(
    g=polars.col('row_nr') // 4,
    j='j',
    )
  )
print(df)
 g (u32)  j (i64)
 0        47
 0        22
 0        82
 0        19
 1        85
 1        15
 1        89
 1        74
 2        26
 2        11
 2        86
 2        81
 3        16
 3        35
 3        60
 3        30
 4        28
 4        94
 4        21
 4        38
shape: (20, 2)
```

I'd like to take top two elements in each group, i.e. end up with this:

```
 g (u32)  j (i64)
 0        47
 0        22
 1        85
 1        15
 2        26
 2        11
 3        16
 3        35
 4        28
 4        94
shape: (10, 2)
```

I tried this:

```
dfj = (df
  .select(
    polars.all().head(2).over('g')
    )
  )
print(dfj)
```

but that results in this exception:

```
exceptions.ComputeError: the length of the window expression did not match that of the group

Error originated in expression: 'col("g").slice(offset=0, length=2).over([col("g")])'
```

I know I can add the row count per group again and filter by that, but I was wondering:

- Why `head` fails here
- If there's a better solution (especially without `groupby`)

Comment: Why without groupby? `df.groupby("g").head(2)`

Comment: @jqurious My understanding is that `groupby` is only available on the top level. So e.g. if you are inside some expression already and want to do groupby at that moment, you cannot. So I'm trying see if there's an alternative way that's "expression-friendly" :)

Comment: If you're already inside `.with_columns()` - that means the result must be the same length as the input (e.g. 20 rows in this case) - but your "filtering" will produce 14 rows, so there is a length mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you know this, but for anyone else stumbling on this: building on your previous question, you can simply do

```py
df.filter(pl.col('j').cumcount().over('g') < 2)
```

Comment: Nice! It all makes sense, but that's only due to the benefid of a hindsight :)